# custom listview with checkbox error in android

Tags: android, android-layout

hi i am creating a custom listview with two chekboxes and problen is when i check a checkbox and scroll down another checkbox adjacent to the checked one also get checked i want to know why it is happening what should i do to avoid that error this is my code

```
public class ListTestActivity extends ListActivity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
String tag = "Events";
String[] presidents;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 // Create an array of Strings, that will be put to our ListActivity
    presidents =getResources().getStringArray(R.array.pres_array);

        ArrayAdapter<Model> adapter = new InteractiveArrayAdapter(this,
                getModel());
        Log.d(tag," event");
        setListAdapter(adapter);
        Log.d(tag," 1");
    }

    private List<Model> getModel() {
        Log.d(tag,"bht");
        int index = presidents.length;
        int positio;
        String Linux;
        //List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        /*for(positio=0;positio<=index ;++positio){
            String Linux="hai";
            List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
            list.add(get(presidents[positio]));
            list.add(get(Linux));
            Log.d(tag," 2");
                     //if(positio>=10){
            return list;

            //}
        }*/
        List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        //int position=0;
        //List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();
        //list.add(get(presidents[position]));
        for(positio=0;positio<index ;positio++){
            Linux=presidents[positio];
            list.add(get(Linux));
        }

        Log.d(tag,"bht1");
        /*list.add(get("Windows7"));
        list.add(get("Suse"));
        list.add(get("Eclipse"));
        list.add(get("Ubuntu"));
        list.add(get("Solaris"));
        list.add(get("Android"));
        list.add(get("iPhone"));*/
        // Initially select one of the items
        //list.get(1).setSelected(true);
        //String re=list.get(1);
        Log.d(tag," event1");
        return list;

    }private Model get(String s) {
        Log.d(tag," event2");
        return new Model(s);
}}


public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {
String tag = "Events";
private final List<Model> list;
private final Activity context;

public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
    protected CheckBox checkbox,checkbox1;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Log.d(tag," 3");
    View view = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
        view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
        final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
        viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
        viewHolder.checkbox1 = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkbox1);
        viewHolder.checkbox
                .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                    @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

Model element = (Model)viewHolder.checkbox.getTag();
    String posit=element.getName();
Log.d(posit,"identifyme");
element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());
                        int dam=viewHolder.checkbox.getId();
                        //Log.d(dam,"bbb");
                        System.out.println("Checked : " + viewHolder.checkbox.getId());

                    }
                });
        viewHolder.checkbox1
        .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {

Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox1.getTag();

    String posit=element.getName();

                Log.d(posit,"identify");
                element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());



                //Log.d(tag,"identifyme");
            }
        });

        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        Log.d(tag,"me");
        viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        viewHolder.checkbox1.setTag(list.get(position));
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        Log.d(tag,"meeee");
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox1.setTag(list.get(position));
    }
    ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
    //String Dis=list.get(position).getName();
    //Log.d(Dis," event7");
    holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    holder.checkbox1.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
    Log.d(tag," event7");

    return view;

}
}

public class Model {
String tag = "Events";
private String name;
private boolean selected;

public Model(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    selected = false;
    Log.d(tag," ev");
}

public String getName() {
    Log.d(tag," eve");
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    Log.d(tag," nt");
    this.name = name;
}

public boolean isSelected() {
    Log.d(tag," t");
    return selected;
}

public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
    Log.d(tag," eventer");
    this.selected = selected;
}

}
```

Comment: Hi, Pls go through the link. Maybe it helps: http://appfulcrum.com/2010/09/12/listview-example-3-simple-multiple-selection-checkboxes/

Comment: thanks basil for the link but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This link also has the same problem and it is resolved in the following link.

[Storing the state of checkbox in listview while using custom BaseAdapter in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7610267/storing-the-state-of-checkbox-in-listview-while-using-custom-baseadapter-in-andr)

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

```
mViewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox)convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
            mViewHolder.checkBox.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) v.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
                    if (cb.isChecked()) {
                        checkBoxArrayList.set(position, true);
                    } else if (!cb.isChecked()) {
                        checkBoxArrayList.set(position, false);
                    }
                }
            });
```

Hi below link may help for you
http://mylearnandroid.blogspot.in/2014/06/listview-problem-while-scrolling.html